# Slicer On Multiple Values In One Column Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, slicers

I have a table that contains many of columns, one of which is a Forum. Here's a sample of the values in the Forum column for various rows:

Forum

---

MD, CIO, CEO, IT

---

CIO, MD

---

MD

---

MD, IT, CFO

---

CEO

---

CEO, IT

---

CEO, CIO

---

IT

---

IT, CFO, CEO

---

CFO

---

I want a slicer that contains all of the possible attributes above, so it looks like this:

MD

---

CEO

---

CFO

---

IT

---

CIO

The idea is that if nothing is selected in the slicer, then the visual shows all rows in the table. But if anything is selected in the slicer, then the visual shows only those rows in which that attribute is present. So, if the user selected "MD", the only rows shown would be those with the following values:

MD, CIO, CEO, IT

---

MD

---

MD, IT, CFO

Comment: Is multi-select permitted in the slicer?

Comment: no only Single select

Answer (score 1):

For the slicer, you need to create a new table with all distinct values. You can follow this below code to generate the **new_table**. Assuming your current table name is "**your_table_name**"

```
let
    Source = your_table_name,
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(Source, {{"Forum", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter(",", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "Forum"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"Forum", type text}}),
    #"Trimmed Text" = Table.TransformColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Forum", Text.Trim, type text}}),
    #"Removed Duplicates" = Table.Distinct(#"Trimmed Text")
in
    #"Removed Duplicates"
```

now create this below **Measure**-

```
check_ = 
VAR _selected = SELECTEDVALUE ( new_table[Forum])
RETURN
IF (
    CONTAINSSTRING ( SELECTEDVALUE (your_table_name[Forum] ), _selected )
        || ISBLANK(_selected),
    1,
    0
)
```

Now, in the table visual, add the newly created measure in the filter section as below-

[image]

The final output will be like-

[image]

Comment: The Forum list also has blanks so when I clear the slicer it does not show data with blank forum.

Comment: What do you mean by BLANK? it's null? or something else?

Comment: Blanks means no value or blank cell

Comment: Can you please try with the updated measure?

Answer (score 0):

Create the following measure:

```
=
VAR SelectedForums =
    VALUES( ForumList[Forum] )
RETURN
    IF(
        HASONEVALUE( ForumList[Forum] ),
        IF(
            COUNTROWS( FILTER( Table1, SEARCH( SelectedForums, Table1[Forum],, 0 ) ) ),
            1,
            0
        ),
        1
    )
```

which you can then drag into the Filters Pane for your desired visuals/pages and set the condition that it be equal to 1.

Comment: I have to create Table 1 with unique values and then apply this measure on Forum table?

Comment: Yes, *ForumList* is a disconnected table comprising a unique list of forums.